# How to convert properties when persisting or instantiating with JPA?

Tags: java, database, jpa

I wonder if JPA is providing any mechanism to persist long for entity that has Date field?

for example

```
@Entity
public class Trade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // some jpa magic here maybe?
    private Date date;
    ...
}
```

when persisting this entity database keeps only longs as fields... But when instatiating this entity it converts long to Date.

When all the DB stuff is handcoded you easily do this if you want. I'm trying to reach flexibility you have when accessing database directly, but I want to do that using JPA. So far this is the only thing i dont know how to do the right way.

---

### UPDATE

Date type is just for an example, what i mean is some Custom type that i know the logic of converting from primitive to Custom instance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store `java.util.Date` as `long`, you need to use a converter (since JPA 2.1). e.g.:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;

public class MyConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, Long> {

    public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(Date attribute) {
        return attribute.getTime();
    }

    public Date convertToEntityAttribute(Long dbData) {
        return new Date(dbData);
    }

}
```

And the annotation for the field:

```
@Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
private Date date;
```

---

See more in [*Example Converter - Java Persistence/Basic Attributes* - Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Example_Converter) (from the highly recommended book [*Java Persistence* - Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence))

Comment: And how does JPA know that it should be persisted as long?

Comment: Or for example if I have some Custom class that can be instantiated from a single primitive type but the instantiation logic is completely custom code...

Comment: OK i've just read it is exactly designed for Date and Calendar, but what about custom case?

Comment: @Vach I updated my answer (you need JPA 2.1 in order to use a converter).

Comment: Now I can even make sure that all instances of entity with same id are the same object, singletone... Which i gave up on :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the temporal annotation

```
@Temporal(DATE)
protected java.util.Date date;
```